# Building a function with codomain equal to a given set of reals.

Tags: functions, cardinals

I was discussing with friends the astounding fact that $\mathbb R$ and the set of real continuous functions were equipotent.

I asked for a proof that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R ^{\mathbb R}$ are not equipotent. Someone asserted that given any set $A \subset \mathbb R$, there exists a function $f\in \mathbb R ^{\mathbb R}$ such that the codomain of $f$ is **exactly** $A$.

Is that true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that comes immediately to mind:

Give some set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, pick any element $a\in A$ and define the function $f\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ by:

$$
   f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x & : x \in A\\
       a & : x \notin A
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$